# Base of eigenvectors for this matrix

Tags: matrices

Does there exist a base of eigenvectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ for the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&0\\-2&0&-1\\-4&2&1\end{pmatrix}?$$
If not, how do I prove that there isn't such a base?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:  There exists a basis of eigenvectors if and only if the algebraic and multiplicity of each eigenvalue is the same.   The algebraic multiplicity is the amount of times each eigenvalue shows up as a root of the characteristic polynomial.   The geometric multiplicity is the dimension of the null space of the associated matrix $A-\lambda I$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You can easely calculate the caracteristic plynomial:
$$
\det\begin{pmatrix}-1-\lambda&0&0\\-2&-\lambda&-1\\-4&2&1-\lambda\end{pmatrix}=
-(1+\lambda)(\lambda^2-\lambda+2)
$$
that has obviously three different roots, so there are three lienarly independent eigenvectors since eigenvectors of different eigenvalues are linearly independent.

But note that two eigenvalues are complex numbers, and the corresponding eigenvectors have complex entries, so there is only one real eigenvector (that cannot be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$).

Comment: But it only has one real root, so only one real eigenvector right?

Comment: yes, only one real eigenvalue with an eigenspace of dimension $1$.

Comment: But what is then the base of eigenvectors?

Comment: Good point, that I've not noted previously ! The answer asks for a basis in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but here the base is it $$\mathbb{C}^3$. I add to my answer.